# Handling arrow keys and tabIndex

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-8

I'm wondering how to "beautify"/"simplify" this code:

```js
function handleKeyDown (e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault()
    myCustomEvent(e)
    return
  }
  if (e.key === 'ArrowDown' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.key === 'ArrowDown'
      ? document &&
        document.activeElement &&
        document.activeElement.nextElementSibling &&
        document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.focus()
      : document &&
        document.activeElement &&
        document.activeElement.previousElementSibling &&
        document.activeElement.previousElementSibling.focus()
  }
}
```

It seems too verbose to me. Is there something I'm doing wrong? How can I write it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through clever usage of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and using objects to store possible events, you can do this.

```
function focus(key){
  const {activeElement:{[key]: elementSibling} = {}} = document;
  if(elementSibling){
    elementSibling.focus();
  }
}

const ACTIONS = {
  ArrowDown: () => focus('nextElementSibling'),
  ArrowUp: () => focus('previousElementSibling'),
  Enter: (e) => myCustomEvent(e)
}

function handleKeyDown (e) {
  const handler = ACTIONS[e.key];
  if(handler) {
    e.preventDefault();
    handler(e);
  }
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
function focus(key){
  const {activeElement:{[key]: elementSibling} = {}} = document;
  if(elementSibling){
    elementSibling.focus();
  }
}

const ACTIONS = {
  ArrowDown: () => focus('nextElementSibling'),
  ArrowUp: () => focus('previousElementSibling'),
  Enter: (e) => myCustomEvent(e)
}

function handleKeyDown (e) {
  console.log(e.key, e.target);
  const handler = ACTIONS[e.key];
  if(handler) {
    e.preventDefault();
    handler(e);
  }
}

// simulating an event
window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyDown);
```

```html
<h3>Click on an element then press ArrowUp or ArrowDown</h3>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: Really amazing! Do you mean `const { activeElement: { [key]: elementSibling } = {} } = document`, right?

Comment: @FredHors good catch and no worries

Comment: I'm trying to use this code with Typescript today and it errors with: `(parameter) key: string
Type 'Element | {} | null' has no matching index signature for type 'string'.ts(2537)`. Any fix?

Comment: Idk, I need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643784/how-to-fix-this-typescript-type-element-null-has-no-matching-index-sig

Answer (score 2):

well I have a question, does `document && document.activeElement` is mandatory?

If so, then there is a way to refactor it:

```js
function handleKeyDown (e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault()
    myCustomEvent(e)
    return
  }
  if (e.key === 'ArrowDown' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    e.preventDefault()
    focusSibling(e.key === 'ArrowDown' && document && document.activeElement)
  }
}

function focusSibling(isNextElemSibling) {
  if (isNextElementSibling && document.activeElement.nextElementSibling)
    document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.focus()
  else if (document.activeElement.previousElementSibling)
    document.activeElement.previousElementSibling.focus()
}
```

Note: Probably you didn't know, but when you do an if or a boolean (true or false) condition the program executes an AND `&&` operator from left to right, and if the first value is `false`, it stops the comparison, because if one value in an AND is false, the statement is false. So, that was a way to simplify your code.

If `document && document.activeElement` is not mandatory, then only change this line:

```js
    focusSibling(e.key === 'ArrowDown')
```

I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

It may be wise to consider [not omitting semicolons](https://dev.to/adriennemiller/semicolons-in-javascript-to-use-or-not-to-use-2nli) in your code

To streamline the code, you can try extracting the 'focus'-function and use a small object to determine where to focus.

```
const tryToFocus = key => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const prevNext = {
    ArrowDown: "nextElementSibling",
    ArrowUp: "previousElementSibling"
  };
  if (Object.keys(prevNext).find(k => key === k)) {
    document &&
    document.activeElement &&
    document.activeElement[prevNext[key]] &&
    document.activeElement[prevNext[key]].focus();
  }
}

function handleKeyDown (e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault(); // may be handled in myCustomEvent?
    return myCustomEvent(e);
  }
  tryToFocus(e.key);
}
```